# angular slickgrid latest version(Current) pagination not showing properly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-slickgrid

This is my code. I am using version 4.1.1

```
AngularSlickgridModule.forRoot({

          registerExternalResources: [new ExcelExportService()],   
          enableAutoResize: true,
          enableGridMenu: true,
          enableExcelExport:true,
          autoHeight: true,
          alwaysShowVerticalScroll: false,
          autoResize: {
            rightPadding: 10,
            container: '#grid-container',
            bottomPadding: 20,   
            minHeight: 250,
            maxWidth: 900,
            minWidth: 200
          },
         
          enableFiltering: true,
          enablePagination: true,
          pagination: {
            pageSizes: [],
            pageSize: 10,
            totalItems: 0,     
          },
}),
```

Page size in showing in 10,25,50....100

But I need custom pagination. So I added pageSizes: [10,50,100,1000],

But it showing default pages (except 10) and  1000,2000...

and also not in sort order. Is I'm doing wrong ?

[image]

EDIT :  After chhange to below code it showing like this..it also showing default page size of slickgrid..

```
 pagination: {
        pageSizes: [10, 200, 250, 500, 5000],
        pageSize: 10
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your page sizes, it won't work with decimal numbers and your `pageSize` must be a valid number that is included in `pageSizes` but isn't in your case because of the decimal number, it works fine in the lib as shown by [Example 30](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/examples/grid-composite-editor.component.ts#L379)

```js
this.gridOptions = {      
  enablePagination: true,
  pagination: {
    pageSize: 10,
    pageSizes: [10, 200, 250, 500, 5000]
  },
};
```

[image: pagination page sizes]

EDIT

There was actually a bug identified to set pagination via global configuration and that was fixed and released under a patch version `4.1.2` of Angular-Slickgrid

Comment: Thanks for the answer..it was typo in the question...sory for that..actualy my input was this..  enablePagination: true,
      pagination: {
        pageSizes: [10, 200, 250, 500, 5000],
        pageSize: 10,
      }, sir, it is showing like updated in the question.. some other number also showing..Actually i m suing graghql

Comment: Sir I am only defined page size in shared module..I am using graphql service...in page size it's also coming default sizes...how to exclude default page size...u only tell wat could be reason..thanks

Comment: I found that it is working correctly when set in the grid component but is not when set through the global configs, so it is a bug. You can open a bug in the library and/or set paginations in your grid component for now

Comment: hope will you fix soon.. Thanks you so much.. https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/issues/879

Comment: i have one more help ..can u pls tel how to get the  extra para detail..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71097344/anguar-slick-grid-get-extraparameter-instance